# ajax выводит только последнюю запись из цикла forEach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

ajax запрос выводит только последнюю запись из цикла,
код ниже:

```
  $.ajax({
                   method: "POST",
                   url: "{{asset('/num')}}",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (data) {
                       var inf;
                       var json_x = data;
                       json_x.forEach(function(item){
                           inf = '<p>'+ item['id'] +"</p>";
                       });
                       insTabl = document.getElementById('table');
                       insTabl.innerHTML = inf;

                   }
               });
```

отправляю я в `div` с айди `id='table'`

Comment: Ну разумеется. В каждой итерации значение inf переписывается заново, а не дополняется. После последней итерации остается последнее значение.

Comment: как решить, с помощью конкатенации? если да то каким образом мне склеить все данные.

Comment: inf += '<p>'+ item['id'] +"</p>";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
json_x.forEach(function(item){
    inf = inf + '<p>'+ item['id'] +"</p>";
});
```

Comment: inf += '<p>'+ item['id'] +"</p>"; я так сделал, но теперь первое значение которое выводится undefined (тоесть, выводиться всё + undefined)))

Comment: Тогда нужно иниализировать так: var inf = "";

Comment: это стандартная практика вывода в js? и еще вопрос inf = ""; в таком случае там не создается пустота? пустой тег или т.д?

Comment: Создается пустая строка. Можете пробел сделать, он в html все равно будет игнорироваться.